# Sqlite3 sort by alpanumeric

Tags: android, sqlite

I've a column which is declared as TEXT, on which I want to sort my SELECTion.
My query goes like this:

```
Select * from tableName ... order by ColumnName COLLATE NOCASE
```

I want the sorting to be:

1. Case insensitive (Im using COLLATE NOCASE)
2. Alpha numeric. Current sorting is 1, 2, 11, A. By default order is 1, 11, 2, A.

Independently 2. can be achieved by ORDER BY cast(ColumnName as int) but how to use it along with COLLATE NOCASE?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an auxiliary column `SELECT *, Convert(int, ColumnName) AS MyAuxiliaryColumn ...` and sort by both `ColumnName` and `MyAuxiliaryColumn`.